# Grunt coffee tab size increase

Tags: tabs, coffeescript, size, gruntjs

I am using grunt-contrib-coffee in my current project and I want to know, how increase tab size in compiled .js file?
By default tab size is equal two spaces, but I want it to make bigger, around 4 spaces.
How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the team suggests running the resultant js [through a js formatter](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2203).

There is a [grunt plugin for this task](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-jsbeautifier), and the config looks like:

```
indentChar: " ",
indentLevel: 0,
indentSize: 4,
```

That oughta get you squared away.